# TelemetryProcessor - Multiple instances overwrite Custom Properties

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a very basic http-POST triggered api which creates a TelemetryClient.  I needed to provide a custom property in this telemetry for each individual request, so I implemented a [TelemtryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling).

However, when subsequent POST requests are handled and a new TelemetryClient is created that seems to interfere with the first request.  I end up seeing maybe a dozen or so entries in App Insights containing the first customPropertyId, and close to 500 for the second, when in reality the number should be split evenly.  It seems as though the creation of the 2nd TelemetryClient somehow interferes with the first.

Basic code is below, if anyone has any insight (no pun intended) as to why this might occur, I would greatly appreciate it.

ApiController which handles the POST request:

```
public class TestApiController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]RequestInput request)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() => ProcessRequest(request));
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Constants.GenericErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    private async void ProcessRequest(RequestInput request)
    {
        string customPropertyId = request.customPropertyId;

        //trace handler creates the TelemetryClient for custom property
        CustomTelemetryProcessor handler = new CustomTelemetryProcessor(customPropertyId);

        //etc.....
    }
}
```

CustomTelemetryProcessor which creates the TelemetryClient:

```
public class CustomTelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly string _customPropertyId;
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public CustomTelemetryProcessor(string customPropertyId)
    {
        _customPropertyId = customPropertyId;

        var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
        builder.Use((next) => new TelemetryProcessor(next, _customPropertyId));

        builder.Build();

        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
    }
}
```

TelemetryProcessor:

```
public class TelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private string CustomPropertyId { get; }
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // Link processors to each other in a chain.
    public TelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next, string customPropertyId)
    {
        CustomPropertyId = customPropertyId;
        Next = next;
    }
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (!item.Context.Properties.ContainsKey("CustomPropertyId"))
        {
            item.Context.Properties.Add("CustomPropertyId", CustomPropertyId);
        }
        else
        {
            item.Context.Properties["CustomPropertyId"] = CustomPropertyId;
        }

        Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to avoid creating Telemetry Client per each request, isntead re-use single static Telemetry Client instance. Telemetry Processors and/or Telemetry Initializers should also typically be registered only once for the telemetry pipeline and not for every request. TelemetryConfiguration.Active is static and by adding new Processor with each request the queue of processor only grows.

The appropriate setup would be to add [Telemetry Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer) (Telemetry Processors are typically used for filtering and Initializers for data enrichment) once into the telemetry pipeline, e.g. though adding an entry to ApplicationInsights.config file (if present) or via code on TelemetryConfiguration.Active somewhere in global.asax, e.g. `Application_Start`:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
```

Initializers are executed in the same context/thread where `Track..(..)` was called / telemetry was created, so they will have access to the thread local storage and or local objects to read parameters/values from.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  I did try the Initializer approach but was seeing same behavior.  Maybe I'm missing the target altogether, could you suggest another approach?  In the code above, each POST request comes with it's own customPropertyID, which needs to show up in each TrackTrace entry associated with processing that request...e.g., http://somedomain/myApi with "CustomProp1" in the header, and http://somedomain/myApi with "CustomProp2" in the header.  Any tracing to app insights needs to include CustomPropertyId so they can be filtered in the portal.  Do Initializers provide this capability?

Comment: How to add `ITelemetryProcessor` to `Application_Start` ?